# Mysql performance update in()

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a performance problem with an UPDATE WHERE id IN().
The pseudocode is (boiled down):

1. Start transaction from PHP:

   ```
   $pdoAdapter->beginTransaction();
   ```
2. query MySQL for price elements that arrive from the external world and are stored in the db and which should be invoiced

   ```
   SELECT id, price 
   FROM incoming_price_elements 
   WHERE <advanced where> 
   FOR UPDATE
   ```
3. Fetch a new invoice id

   ```
   SELECT id 
   FROM invoice_id_counter 
   FOR UPDATE; 
   UPDATE invoice_id_counter SET id=id+1;
   ```
4. Create an invoice in PHP with a lot of summing and other aggregation and store the result

   ```
   INSERT INTO invoices (id, total_price)
   VALUES (<id from 3.>, <total price summed>);
   ```
5. Update all the incoming_price_elements to mark them invoiced

   ```
   UPDATE incoming_price_elements 
   SET invoice_id=<id from 3.> 
   WHERE id IN (<all ids selected in 2.>);
   ```
6. Commit

---

My problem is that step 5 is pretty slow (in the area of seconds) and it blocks the id counter in step 3.
The number of ids to transfer is more than 10.000 ids and the id is the primary key.

Any suggestions on how to optimize this? I was thinking about creating a temporary table and selecting all the ids into that, but I have zero experience in temporary tables.

Comment: Is there a reason for incrementing ids yourself instead of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Do you need the invoice ids in some other table (hence need to know the id before doing step 5)?

Answer (score 1):

instead of  a IN clause you could use INNER JOIN

```
  UPDATE incoming_price_elements a
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id
      FROM incoming_price_elements 
      WHERE  <advanced where> 

  ) t ON t.id = a.id 
  SET invoice_id= <id from 3.>
```

this should improve your performance for this part of your "transaction"

Comment: That is a fine suggestion; but I worry that new rows has been added to the incoming_price_elements during the calculations in 4 and therefore, the results will not be exactly the same

Comment: If you .. use correctly the transaction   .. or you use trigger  you can manage for avoid that this happen this can't happen ..  .. and also  you can performe the subquery  with the proper advanced  where for avoid the situation you are worried ..   and the execution fo the INNER JOIN is more fast but also is executute juts in one time not  with severel iteration over the same data

Comment: I'm not sure how I can avoid data being added while in a transaction? With InnoDB I don't do table locking but only row locking?

Comment: Try take  a look at trigger .. .. .. but to me  seems not related  to improve the performance with IN clause

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of your comments, data is 'continually' being added to `incoming_price_elements`?  And that table is sort of a "staging area"?  And one problem is that if new items are added before you finish processing, then there is trouble?

If so, then let's flip-flop.

```
CREATE TABLE next_icp LIKE incoming_price_elements;
RENAME TABLE incoming_price_elements TO prev_icp,
             next_icp TO incoming_price_elements;   -- swap in an empty table
-- now process `prev_icp` as discussed already.
```

As for the sluggishness, let's try to do more processing *before* starting the transaction.

Can you have some extra columns in `incoming_price_elements` to handle the "lot of summing and other aggregation"?  After that start the transaction, do the other stuff, and finally (as scaisEdge suggests) do a "multi-table UPDATE" (with a `JOIN`) instead of `IN`.

If that is still too invasive, then do the ids 100 at a time, not all at once.  `UPDATE` must save the old rows in case of a crash (etc); that gets to be costly.  By breaking it up; you let other connections get some work done.

That is put a loop around steps 1..6, and focus on only 100 rows at a time, until you exhaust the staging table.  This will let other ids to be grabbed in the middle; I hope that is OK.